# How to get texture channel ID from material in Assimp?

Tags: 3d, assimp

I found that each mesh has textureCoords in form of textureCoords[i][j] where "i" is a vertexID and "j" is texture channelID that says which particular texture from material is used.

I know that I can find textures used by mesh using material->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, n, &texturePath) but how do I get channelID and is my understanding that "j" stays for channelID correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the texture path directly from the Material.

```
if(material->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) > 0) {
    aiString path;
    material->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &path);
    printf("Diffuse Texture: %s\n", path.data.c_str());
}
```

For Texture Coordinates:

```
if(aiM->mTextureCoords[0])
    for (int j = 0; j < aiM->mNumVertices; j++)
        vd.texCoord1 = Vector2(aiM->mTextureCoords[0][j].x, aiM->mTextureCoords[0][j].y);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. From your example I found that "i' stays for channel and "j" for vertexId (i taught it was opposite). But there is one thing I would like to ask: if material contains multiple textures how do I find which channel ( or "i" in mTextureCoords[i][j]) corresponds to  particular texture in material (because material can contain up to 8 textures and then "i" will be in range from 0 to 7 and I have no clue which "i" is related to which of these 8 textures)

Comment: Usually Meshes with different textures will be stored as separate mesh within the node. So most likely you don't have to use more than one texture coordinates. The only scenario when your'll need 2nd channel of texture coordinates is when you use light map texture which usually don't use the same coord as defuse texture.

Answer (score 0):

You can get channelID for a texture with AI_MATKEY_UVWSRC (If it is defined explicitly).

```
// gets channelID for 0th Diffuse texture
int uvChannel = -1;
if (aiReturn_SUCCESS == material->Get(AI_MATKEY_UVWSRC(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0), uvChannel)) {
    std::cout << "uvChannel: " << uvChannel << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "uvChannel: Not defined" << std::endl;
}
```

It is documented at "[How to map UV channels to textures (MATKEY_UVWSRC)](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/materials.html#uvwsrc)".